# Free or FOSS Elevation API for Heightmaps (image files) instead of elevation points

Tags: api, terrain, unity3d

I'm coming from a Blender background, in which simple FOSS extensions exist (like BlenderGIS) that download SRTM/Aster Elevation Data and make a terrain based on this. I'd like to make something similar in the Unity game engine (*I can easily implement web requests, it is engine-agnostic*), in which the user makes a bounding-box over a map, and then the Elevation Data is downloaded in the form of a Heightmap Image file (I am not sure what this format is called, but the lowest point is black and the highest is white). A simple terrain object is then created and the image file is converted to a file Unity's terrain heightmaps can handle (something like `.jpg` to `.png`).

I would also like it so you can feed in the **4 points** (*x/y values of lat/long*) to download the data of a box instead of manually generating a file that has all the values.

Comment: [OpenTopography API](https://opentopography.org/developers#API)? I've not used it so can't comment on it.

Answer (score 1):

As from the broad answer from [@user2856](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/2856/user2856), the OpenTopography API does actually provide an API, and some datasets don't even need an API key. You can visit them [here](https://portal.opentopography.org/apidocs) for the Swagger API Docs. It checks all of my requirements as it has *4 Coordinates* for a bounding-box selection and has multiple datasets (including SRTM).